# iOS App which uses Network Extension will hang on upgrade if the VPN is enabled

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, vpn, networkextension

Whenever I try to upgrade an app that has the Network Extension (NEPacketTunnelProvider) to a new version and the VPN is in "Connecting" or "Connected" state, the upgrade will always hang with the below message in the console logs:

```
Oct  7 13:43:24 XXX-iPad SpringBoard(FrontBoard)[47] <Notice>: Error acquiring hold on plugins for com.example.apple-samplecode.SimpleTunnel.myapp2: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=14 "plug-ins are busy" UserInfo={busyPlugInUUIDs=(
        {
        XPCExtensionBundleIdentifier = "com.example.apple-samplecode.SimpleTunnel.myapps.PacketTunnel.myapp2";
    }
), NSLocalizedDescription=plug-ins are busy}
```

Even if I wait a long time it never finishes, sometimes showing around 55% completion and sometimes the icon is black. If I click on the icon and restart the upgrade sometimes it works, but then I have to go back and set up VPN a second time. Sometimes I see an error message which asks if I want to retry the upgrade.

This will be a serious issue for customers as it seems to happen every time, at least on iOS 10. I have not been able to find any reasonable workaround.

I have written up a bug with Apple but all they communicated was it is a duplicate of an existing Open issue (27872696). They haven't been able to provide any workaround yet.

Stopping the VPN before upgrade time does allow the upgrade to work without issue, but this is a very bad user experience.

If anyone has seen this issue or can provide a workaround or other information, please let me know.

BTW, I have reproed it with Apple's latest Simple Tunnel app, so it is not anything weird my app is doing. I can reproduce by doing initial download and upgrade over Intunes using an IPA made in XCode, but I also see this when doing upgrade from the app store which is the biggest issue.

UPDATE: This thread discusses where Apple says it is a known issue. If this issue is impacting you please consider adding a response to it since there is an Apple person on the thread.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61659

Comment: I'm experiencing this same problem.

Comment: Not fixed in iOS 10.1 beta 3 either ):

Comment: Looks like this was fixed in a recent version of iOS 10

Comment: This is still happening on iOS 17.